# Event class serialization

Tags: c++, serialization, macros

Hello I'm checking various object serialization methods in C++, but I can't find the appropriate solution. The one I am checking now is using macro to serialize various classes. The code compiles, but I get `0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCC8.` when function    `serialize_example();` is calling `Event* newEvent = dynamic_cast<Event*>(Persistent::load(stream));`

The exception occurs in `Persistent * obj = dynamic_cast<Persistent *>(clone);` call. Anyone can help me to solve this problem? Here is the code:

```
void serialize_example()
{
auto_ptr<Event> event(new Event());

fstream file("try.data",
    ios::out | ios::in | ios::binary | ios::trunc);

ArchiveFile stream(&file);

if (!file)
    throw "Unable to open file for writing";

event->store(stream);

file.seekg(0, ios::beg);

Event* newEvent = dynamic_cast<Event*>(Persistent::load(stream));

event.reset(newEvent);

file.close();
}
```

**Event.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "Persist.h"
#define PERSISTENT_DECL(className) \
public: \
 virtual Clonable* createObj()  \
{ \
return new className(); \
} \
 private: \
static AddClonable _addClonable; 
#define PERSISTENT_IMPL(className) \
AddClonable className::_addClonable(#className, new className());
class Event : public Persistent {
private:
 int _id;
public:
Event() : _id(0) {}
virtual ~Event() {}
int getId()  { return _id; }
protected:
virtual void serialize(Archive& stream)
{
    if (stream.isStoring())
        stream << _id;
    else
        stream >> _id;
}

PERSISTENT_DECL(Event)
};
 PERSISTENT_IMPL(Event)
```

**Persist.cpp**

```
#include "Persist.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
Archive& Archive::operator<<(int val)
{
write(&val, sizeof(int));
return *this;
}

Archive& Archive::operator>>(int& val)
{
read(&val, sizeof(int));
return *this;
}

Archive& Archive::operator<<(const string& str)
{
int length = str.length();
*this << length;
write(str.c_str(), sizeof(char) * length);
return *this;
}

Archive& Archive::operator>>(string& str)
{
int length = -1;
*this >> length;
vector<char> mem(length + 1);
char* pChars = &mem[0];
read(pChars, sizeof(char) * length);
mem[length] = NULL;
str = pChars;
return *this;
}
void ArchiveFile::write(const void* buffer, size_t length)
{
_stream->write((const char*)buffer, length);
if (!*_stream)
    throw "ArchiveFile::write Error";
}

void ArchiveFile::read(void* buffer, size_t length)
{
_stream->read((char*)buffer, length);
if (!*_stream)
    throw "ArchiveFile::read Error";
}
void Persistent::store(Archive& stream) const
{
string className = typeid(*this).name();

className = className.substr(className.find(' ') + 1);

stream << className;

int ver = version();

stream << ver;

stream.setDirection(true);

const_cast<Persistent *>(this)->serialize(stream);
}
Persistent* Persistent::load(Archive& stream)
{
string className;
stream >> className;

Clonable* clone = Clonables::Instance().create(className.c_str());
if (clone == NULL)
    throw "Persistent::load : Error creating object";

auto_ptr<Clonable> delitor(clone);

Persistent * obj = dynamic_cast<Persistent *>(clone);
if (obj == NULL) {
    throw "Persistent::load : Error creating object";
}

int ver = -1;

stream >> ver;

if (ver != obj->version())
    throw "Persistent::load : unmatched version number";

stream.setDirection(false);

obj->serialize(stream);

delitor.release();

return obj;
}
```

**Dynamics.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#include <map>


 class Clonable
{
public:
virtual ~Clonable() {}

virtual Clonable* createObj()  = 0;
};


class Clonables {
private:
typedef map<string, const Clonable*> NameToClonable;
NameToClonable __clonables;
private:
Clonables() {}
Clonables(const Clonables&);                 // Prevent copy-construction
Clonables& operator=(const Clonables&);      //  Prevent assignment
~Clonables()
{
    for (NameToClonable::const_iterator it = __clonables.begin(); it !=       __clonables.end(); it++) {
        const Clonable* clone = it->second;
        delete clone;
    }
    __clonables.clear();
}
public:
static Clonables& Instance()
{
    static Clonables instance;   // Guaranteed to be destroyed.                              
    return instance;    // Instantiated on first use.
}
public:
void addClonable(const char* className, const Clonable* clone)
{
    string name = className;
    NameToClonable::const_iterator it = __clonables.find(name);
    if (it == __clonables.end()) {
        __clonables[name] = clone;
    }
}
Clonable* create(const char *className)
{
    string name = className;
    NameToClonable::const_iterator it = __clonables.find(name);
    if (it == __clonables.end()) return NULL;

    const Clonable* clone = it->second;

}
};
class AddClonable {
public:
AddClonable(const char* className, const Clonable* clone) {
    Clonables::Instance().addClonable(className, clone);
}
};
```

Comment: That's too much code to analyse, and there is no MCVE for us to try and compile it ourselves. Therefore, no answer but only a comment: look into Boost Serialization.

Comment: You're missing a return statement in ‘Cloneables.create(...)‘ and possibly more code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Boost.Serialization for your example. I want to give an example of me here. You can easily serialize your object overloading & operator.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>

struct plane {
    std::string id;
    std::string name;
    int x;

private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & id;
        ar & name;
        ar & x;
    }
};

int serialization()
{
    {
        plane old_plane;
        old_plane.id = "12345";
        old_plane.id = "plane foo";
        old_plane.x = 12345;

        // boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
        std::ofstream ofs("filename");
        boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(ofs);
        oa << old_plane;
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    plane new_plane;

    std::ifstream ifs("filename");
    //boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
    boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(ifs);

    ia >> new_plane;

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    std::cout << new_plane.id << " ";
    std::cout << new_plane.name << " ";
    std::cout << new_plane.x << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```